# Store an incremented int number that is on a char variable

Tags: c

I've been trying store the 1 to temp so that it increments the next time the function is ran again. The prints are just for debugging purposes.

```
void CreatAccountNumbers(char *startString)
{
    ACCOUNTNUM accountInfo;
    //this function is for the system generation of bank client account numbers
    int temp; //first int
    temp++;
    char tempChar=temp; //int to char
    tempChar+='0'; 
    char finalString[30]=" ";
    strcpy(finalString,startString);
    printf("\nstartstring:%s",startString);
    printf("\ntempChar:%c",tempChar);
    printf("\nfinal string:%s",finalString);
    finalString[5]+=tempChar;
    temp+=tempChar;
    printf("\nfinal string with tempchar:%s",finalString);

    strcpy(accountInfo.sAccountNum,finalString);
    printf("\nvalue on structure:%s",accountInfo.sAccountNum);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] and explain what the problem is and also show a [mcve], the problem might be in the code that calls `CreatAccountNumbers` and there may be other problems in the declaration of `ACCOUNTNUM `

Answer (score 0):

The variable `temp` was never initialized properly. So, it will produce undefined behavior.

You can initialize it like this:

```
  int temp = 0;
```

Now, `finalString` is not properly initialized, you should write it like this:

```
 char finalString[30]= {}; // all elements will be 0
```

Also, ASCII value `1` will not be printed on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is something like this.

- Use `static` qualifier to store the `sequence` number.
- `sequence` will retain its value between calls to generate next account number.
- NOTE : This value will reset once the program restarts. You may want to load the last `sequence` number from an external source during startup.

```c
void ai_get_newACnum (const char* ac_prefix, char* new_ac, const size_t naclen) {
    static int sequence = 1;
    snprintf (new_ac, naclen, "%s_%09d", ac_prefix, sequence++);
}
```

You can call for you structure like : sizeof if `accountInfo.sAccountNum` is an char-array, otherwise the actual `dynamic-memory` size.

```c
ai_get_newACnum (startString, accountInfo.sAccountNum, sizeof(accountInfo.sAccountNum));
```

To test :

```c
#define MAX_ACNUM_STRLEN 64

int main (void) {
    char nxtACNumber [MAX_ACNUM_STRLEN];
    for (int ai = 0; ai < 12; ++ai) {
        ai_get_newACnum ("myAcSeq", nxtACNumber, sizeof (nxtACNumber));
        printf ("New Account Number : %s\n", nxtACNumber);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which generates :

```
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000001
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000002
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000003
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000004
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000005
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000006
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000007
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000008
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000009
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000010
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000011
New Account Number : myAcSeq_000000012
```

Comment: I just noticed my sequence is stored in the structure. Can i still use the same method in incrementing it?

Comment: Then approach totally changes, add the structure details to the question for clarity.